# Access [innerHTML] value within child component

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I want to access [innerHTML] within child component

Hi All

I have component call 'contact-us' within that component I have below field.

```
`<div [innerHTML] = "legalContent.disclaimer"></div>`
```

I call this component within another component. But the issue is that innerHTML value is not dislaying within my child component.

This is my contact.ts code

```
async getLegalContent()  {
this.legalContent = await this.legalService.getLegaPages().toPromise();
this.legalService.legalInfo = this.legalContent;
 }
```

I call an API within legal service to get the data.

can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For secure Angular blocks some html content that you wanna set in `innerHTML`. You can use `DomSanitizer` with a pipe:

#### Custom pipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class Safe {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(style) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(style);
    //return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(style);
    // return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustXxx(style); - see docs
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
<div [innerHTML] = "legalContent.disclaimer | safeHtml"></div>
```

Now you should see the content.

Comment: I tried by creating new custom pipe. But still  can't see the content

Comment: Can you give me more informations? The content of the variable you using (console.log) and where you set it

Comment: Its a typo.... `legaContent.disclaimer` instead of `legalContent.disclaimer`

Comment: oh sorry. It is a mistake by me when typing the question. It is correct in my code

Comment: Then please show me a console.log of the legalContent

Comment: {disclaimer: '<em>**Please do not use this for sharing any personal information</em>'}
disclaimer: "<em>**Please do not use this for sharing any personal information</em>"